# Query Builder - Get number of rows alongside another query

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony, query-builder

I'm working on a photo contest and have such a relation

- All **image**s have and id, a title, an author and a filename
- All **vote**s have an id, the id of the image the vote is made for and a data

Here are the entities in the project:

***Image***

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Image {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, name="file_name")
     * @var string $fileName
     */
    protected $fileName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, name="title", nullable=true)
     * @var string $title
     */
    protected $title = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, name="author", nullable=true)
     * @var string $author
     */
    protected $author = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="upload_at")
     */
    protected $uploadDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", name="in_pool")
     */
    protected $inPool;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set fileName
     *
     * @param string $fileName
     *
     * @return Image
     */
    public function setFileName($fileName)
    {
        $this->fileName = $fileName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fileName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFileName()
    {
        return $this->fileName;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     *
     * @return Image
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set author
     *
     * @param string $author
     *
     * @return Image
     */
    public function setAuthor($author)
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get author
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    /**
     * Set uploadDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $uploadDate
     *
     * @return Image
     */
    public function setUploadDate($uploadDate)
    {
        $this->uploadDate = $uploadDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get uploadDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUploadDate()
    {
        return $this->uploadDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set inPool
     *
     * @param boolean $inPool
     *
     * @return Image
     */
    public function setInPool($inPool)
    {
        $this->inPool = $inPool;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get inPool
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getInPool()
    {
        return $this->inPool;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->uploadDate = new \DateTime('now');
        $this->inPool = false;
    }
}
```

***Vote***

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\Image;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Vote
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Image")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $image;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="date")
     */
    protected $date;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     *
     * @return Vote
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->date = new \DateTime('now');
    }

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Image $image
     *
     * @return Vote
     */
    public function setImage(Image $image = null)
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Image
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }
}
```

Now on my main page I have a simple query builder displaying all the images with their properties inside a table.

Now I would like to add to each row of the table a field **displaying the number of votes each image has**.

That would mean I need to get `count` of every row with a id being the id of the current image.

What would be the best way to achieve this with QueryBuilder?

Keep in mind that I would like to get the values for *all of the images*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a repository class for `Vote` entity (it should be `VoteRepository`, create this class if it don't exist already) add method `countVotesForImage`:

```
/**
 * Method returns count of votes assigned to an Image entity
 *
 * @param Image $image Instance of Image entity
 *
 * @return int Result of count query
 */
public function countVotesForImage(Image $image)
{
    $imageID = $image->getId();

    if (!is_numeric($imageID)) {
        // for new images which are not stored in DB
        // we dont have to query database
        return 0;
    }

    return (int) $this->createQueryBuilder('v')
        ->select('COUNT(v.id)')
        ->where('v.image = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $image->getId())
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

After in any controller you will be able to use it:

```
$image; // this variable should contain valid class of Image entity
$counter = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Vote')
    ->countVotesForImage($image);
```

The last step is to pass it to view:

```
return $this->render(
    'your/template.html.twig',
    array('counter' => $counter)
);
```

If you would like to take all votes for all images, please add this method to `ImageRepository`:

```
/**
 * Method returns count of votes assigned to an Image entity
 *
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function countVotesForAllImages()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
        ->select(array(
            'i',
            'COUNT(i.id) as counter'
        ))
        ->join('i.votes', 'v')
        ->groupBy('i.id')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

If you add this method, you'll also need to add in Vote entity:

```
/**
 * This is internal variable, it does not have to be mapped into database field
 * @var int Counter of votes for an Image
 */
private $counter;

/**
 * Method sets internal counter of votes for an Image
 *
 * @param int $counter
 */
public function setCounter($counter)
{
    $this->counter = $counter;
}

/**
 * Method gets internal counter of votes for an Image
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getCounter()
{
    return $this->counter;
}
```

Method proposed by @Markownikow will also work, but it takes all votes form DB into memory, hydrate them, and after count as array items in memory. As it would be an overkill, I suggest to choose my method.

Answer (score 0):

in Vote add inversedBy

```
/**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Image", inversedBy="votes")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
         */
        private $image;
```

in Image entity add property $votes

```
  /**
         * One image has many votes
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Vote", mappedBy="image")
         */
        private $votes;

  function __construct() {
       $this-> votes = new ArrayCollection()
  }
```

then with getter you can get votes collection:

```
function getVotes()
{
   return $this->votes;
}
```

and ArrayCollection has count() method so you can use it to get amount of votes

Comment: Used your code. My select looks like this:
` $images = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('i, count(i.votes)')
            ->from('AppBundle:Image', 'i')
            ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();`

But I get
` Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or` `SingleValuedAssociationField expected.`

Comment: This approach takes all votes form DB into memory, hydrate them, and after count as array items in memory. As it would be an overkill, I suggest to choose my method (see my answer).

Comment: I think michail_w has better way, actually i also wanted to propose something like he did in his countVotesForAllImages() method but I wasn't confident about correct syntax, If about your error I am not quite sure but maybe its because it should be "->orderBy('i.id', 'DESC')  - 'i' alias missing